# C# webform calendar

Tags: c#, webforms, calendar

Have a webform that I'm looking to have a calendar that a user can choose the date from the calendar and it then displays the selected date in a textbox. When I choose a calendar from the toolbox how do i minimize the calendar on the generated webpage so it doesn't display the calendar all the time, like only when a drop down is chosen (it takes up alot of space and looks awful).

tried to dispaly the selected date like this but it doesn't work:

```
TextBox10.Text = "Date" +  Calendar1.SelectedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of what you are trying to do I would recommend either using the [AJAX Control Toolkits Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) or using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) functionality

Comment: I'm doing this step by step with website and not working: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar_Simple.ashx                     doesn't recognize calendarextender